# Connecting a chrome extension to an SQL server

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, google-chrome-extension

So basically I have a chrome extension that runs a content-sript.js.
Its only pages are the extension's options.

The extension shows the mouse's coordinates on the mouse's tooltip.
You can find the extension here:
https://github.com/Evaw/coordinates

I'm struggling with using a server to save all the user's mouse coordinates.
Already tried Firebase, LocalStorage (which is fine but useless), SQL server and Indexeddb.

Can't use require, cant import, etc.
Tried using a background.js as well, and ran into the same problems of defining the database access.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Either a) enable an API in sql server on localhost and connect to it from the extension using xhr/fetch or b) write a separate connector utility and use it via nativeMessaging.

Comment: I did but still can't do it. I edited the question.